# Configure Kong plugin to only trigger for one or more methods?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

Is there any way to configure a plugin to trigger only for a given method or set of methods?

```
-routes: 
  - name: some-route
  - paths:
      - /some-path
      plugins:
        - name: some-plugin
          methods: GET # Only run plugin for GET
          configuration:
            some-config:
            - foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the method on the route level

```
-routes: 
  - name: some-route
    methods:
      - GET # Only run plugin for GET
    paths:
      - /some-path
    plugins:
      - name: some-plugin
          
          configuration:
            some-config:
            - foo
```